# Data not binding to ionic view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

this is my ionic view [click here to see ionic view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ9De.png) 
and here is my controller [click here to see controller data while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCmt9.png) 
Data is coming through service from  api but not binding to view .Please  help me it has wasted my whole day.

Comment: can you show so code for controller and services?

Comment: angular.module('starter.services')

.factory('productResource',
 [
 "$resource",
"appSetting",
productResource 
 ])

function productResource($resource, appSetting) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    return $resource(appSetting.serverPath + "/api/Products/:id");
};

this  is the service code

Comment: .controller('ChatsCtrl', function ($scope, productResource) {
        productResource.query(function (data,$scope) {
           $scope.products = data;

           debugger;
       });
   
    $scope.remove = function (chat) {
        Chats.remove(chat);
    };
})

Comment: sir is this information enough??

Comment: any thing you get in controller?

Comment: p[lease click on the image

Comment: $scope.products
[edescription: "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle."price: 19.95productCode: "GDN-0011"productId: 1productName: "Leaf Rake"releaseDate: "2009-03-19T12:30:00+05:30"__proto__: e]

this is the console output on debugging

Comment: Try $scope.products = data.data

Comment: not working undefindd while debuging

Comment: you don't need $scope as arg in the callback function.

Comment: yup thanks it workes